# Генерация элементов формы на view в зависимости от тип

Tags: php, laravel, form

У меня есть сущность анкеты, анкета содержит вопросы. У вопроса есть тип (текст, список). Необходимо генерировать страницу с вопросами анкеты. В зависимости от типа необходимо генерировать для вопроса соответствующий элемент формы. Есть ли готовые решения или пакеты, которые помогут это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Что-то наподобие такого:

```
                @foreach($questions as $questionItem)
                    @if($questionItem->type == 'list')
                        <select name="question_{{ $questionItem->id }}">
                            @foreach($questionItem->options as $option)
                                <option value="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->title }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    @else
                        <input name="question_{{ $questionItem->id }}">
                    @endif
                @endforeach
```